# JSF2 Composite Component in Grails?

Tags: grails, composite-component

Is it possible to create reusable composite components (in JSF wording) in Grails? For the ones who do not know composites, here is the external link to [JEE6 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think Grails custom Tag Libraries are the closes thing to JSF composite components

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs